# Write Pandas data frame to a file with a leading space

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe of the form

```
YYYYMMDD HHMMSS JJJJJ.JJJJ   
20050414  120000  53474.5     
20050415  120000  53475.5
```

I would like to concatenate these lines to an existing file, with the output looking like

```
PREVIOUS DATA HERE
YYYYMMDD HHMMSS JJJJJ.JJJJ
 20050414 120000 53474.5
 20050415 120000 53475.5
```

That is, with a leading space in each of the data frame's data lines, but not the column header line.

The following produces output in the correct format, but without the space.

```
df[['YYYYMMDD','HHMMSS']] = df[['YYYYMMDD','HHMMSS']].astype(int)
with open('myfile', 'a') as f:
  df.to_csv(f, sep=' ', index=False)
```

I tried converting the first column to a string type and added a leading space, but the output is then not in the correct format.  I imagine there is a very easy solution, but Google search produces a lot of hits on how to *remove* rather than *add* white space.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `line_terminator` parameter by adding a space after the newline : `line_terminator='\n '`.

```
with open('myfile', 'a') as f:
    df.to_csv(f, line_terminator='\n ', sep=' ', index=False)
```

It doesn't move the header, and all other lines get the wanted offset.

Comment: Nice!  Thank you!